# Raspivid & Avconv add watermark and save .mp4 from Youtube output stream

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, raspberry-pi, raspbian, avconv

I have this **ffmpeg** command **working** with a **USB webcam** in my **raspberry pi**:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 30 -aspect 16:9 -c:v h264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -maxrate:v 820k -bufsize:v 820k -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental -flags +global_header -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5 [out]" -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX|video.flv"
```

This command adds a **watermark** (logo), **saves mp4 to disk** and **broadcast to youtube** the stream. It is working, but my raspberry pi **hangs** because it gets out of memory (CPU and RAM).

This is why i have changed my USB webcam to **raspicam 2.1**.

Now i am trying to do the same but using **raspivid** and **avconv**. But this is the only command i have already managed to use:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX
```

I am looking to replicate functionality but with raspicam 2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is not possible to add logo, save and emit to youtube is it possible only to save and emit?.

Comment: Does it run out of RAM quickly? Like maybe encoding can't keep up or something?  Hmm...

Comment: Yes, it is quickly... and streaming isnt smooth so i need to use raspivid and avconv wich streams smoothl I dont know if saving mp4 file while streaming without adding any watermark is going to collapse Rpi or not. Do you know how to do this with raspivid and avconv?.